# Every time I replace Fragment memory usage increases

Tags: android, android-fragments, view, memory-leaks

you can find  my fragment replacement code and memory leak prevention attempts below

```
  FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_CLOSE);
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, f);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();
```

Sample `onDestroyView` //i assign  every **global variable views** to null

```
    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {

    propertyList = null;
    pa = null;
    db = null;

    mainView = null;
    super.onDestroyView();
}
```

I assign null every view on every fragments destroy method that references context. But assigning null is not doing any good to memory. Where am i doing wrong?

Comment: There is no need to dereference views in `onDestroyView()`. As long as you don't reference your views from outside the fragment, you won't leak them. What tool did you use to monitor your memory usage? Did you confirm that you were leaking the views?

Comment: I keep track memory usage with Android Studio. There is no outside reference. When i replace a fragment, the previous fragment's memory is notleaked, why?